# Change \ref text

Tags: hyperref

I wonder whether I can change displayed text in `\ref` **globally** for a `\label` referencing a numbered environment. Concretely:

Let's suppose I have a theorem called "Important Proof".

```
\begin{theorem}[Important Proof]\label{IP}
Trivial.
\end{theorem}
```

Then `\ref{IP}` would display something like `1.1.1`. I however want to change that text only sporadically, so that this specific proof gets displayed e.g. with `Important Proof`, but all other proofs stay unaffected.

What did I mean with **globally**? I saw some workarounds using `\hyperref` every single time, but this does not seem really convincing; I would like to have some kind of redefinition, so that I can just use something like `\ref` s.t. I don't have to insert the text every single time manually.

Comment: The [`nameref` package](//ctan.org/pkg/nameref) provides `\nameref` that works like that. Redefining `\ref` globally to be `\nameref` won't be a good idea though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}[Important Proof]%
\makeatletter\def\@currentlabel{Important Proof}\makeatother
\label{IP}
Trivial.
\end{theorem}

\ref{IP}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks! How did you infer that one must redefine \@currentlabel? Just by reading the hyperref documentation?

Comment: I know a bit about the LaTeX and hyperref code.

Comment: Sure, I just wonder how to get to the solution as a mere mortal :D

Comment: I'm a mere mortal and I learned it because it is not a secret. You can find over 600 hits with `\@currentlabel` and more if you google. At some time in the past I probably read one answer about it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this would be possible *simply* without redefining `\ref`, which is probably considerably more work than you're interested in (or than the problem is really worth).  However, you could define a wrapper macro that would take care of what you want.  Make sure you use `\usepackage{ifthen}` (this is a standard LaTeX package), and define a macro `\nref` like so:

```
\def\nref#1{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{IP}}{%
        ``Important Proof''%
    }{%
        \ref{#1}%
    }%
}%
```

Then, anytime you'd use `\ref`, use `\nref` instead.  This resulted in the following references, when I defined two figures:

[image: Results]

I hope that answers your difficulty.